# How to convert a string to a float in my dataframe? (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with my dataframe in Python. Dataframe looks like this:

```
Timestamp                  cpu_system           Host
 2018-01-09 20:03:22     1.3240749835968018     pwp2
 2017-09-30 21:03:22     2.0                    pwp2 
 ...................................................
```

When I check on dtypes on this dataframe, I get this:

```
   timestamp     object
   cpu_system    object
   host          object
 dtype: object
```

I want to change cpu_system into float. Running this code:

```
 df[['cpu_system']] = df[['cpu_system']].astype(float)
```

Getting this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: value
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: `df['cpu_system'] = df['cpu_system'].astype(float)`

Answer (score 1):

You can first check what values cannot be converted by:

```
print (df[pd.to_numeric(df['cpu_system'], errors='coerce').isnull()])
```

and then use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `erors='coerce'` for convert bad values to `NaN`:

```
df['cpu_system'] = pd.to_numeric(df['cpu_system'], errors='coerce')
```

And filter problematic values out if necessary by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['cpu_system'].notnull()]
```

Comment: Getting an error when running the first two lines:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: to_numeric() got an unexpected keyword argument 'erors'